# In Android, how do I give a Rect an X and Y position?

Tags: android, rect

I'm trying to draw a simple Rect on a Canvas that is at the X coordinate of 360, and the Y coordinate of 0. I can draw my Rect if I make the X coordinate to 0, but when I make it 360, the square becomes distorted and becomes a rectangular shape rather than a square anymore. My screen size is 640px wide, so there should be no problem here. I can draw Bitmaps with the same specifications and it will draw normally. Why is it that Rects don't draw correctly? Is it somehow that the X coordinate is only in DP rather than PX? Then why does that affect the actual size of the Rect? I'm really confused.

```
            Rect square6 = new Rect();
            square6.set(360, 0, 60, 60);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should read the reference to the [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) in Android, The set func of Rect is public void set (int left, int top, int right, int bottom), you set your rect start from (360, 0) and ends at (60, 60), you should change the parmas to (360, 0, 420, 60). It will work.

Comment: I need to have a Rect that is 60x60 and is on the X position of 360, and the Y position of 0.

Comment: This will make the rect draw at (360, 0) with size of 60x60, but you should make sure the size of your view which you want to draw this rect will be much larger than 420x60

Comment: Oh, ok. Thanks! Sorry, I misunderstood.

Comment: It worked, by the way. Thanks for the help. I'm glad I know how it works now. I also read the code reference just now. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @lishali i am facing same problem since 2-3 days, but after reading your answer i got my problem where i am going wrong....and it's working fine now....